# windowed selection from a list in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

Suppose I have a list

`a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I randomly choose an index using,

`i = np.random.choice(np.arange(a.size))`

and now, I want to select a symmetric interval around i of some size, say 2. So for example for the given list, if the index `i = 5` is selected, I get something like

```
print(a[i-2:i+2+1])
>> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This works fine
however, if i happens to be near one of the end points, `i = 1`. Using what I have i get,

```
print(a[i-2:i+2+1])
>> []
```

Instead I want something it to print an asymmetric interval, like `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

if i = 8

```
print(a[i-2:i+2+1])
>> [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

like I want it to too, so being near the end point doesn't seem to matter. The closest I have gotten to a solution is (say for i = 1)

```
print([a[0:i+3] if a[i-2:i+2+1] == [] else a[i-2:i+2+1] ])
>> [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

But this returns, `[[0,1,2,3]]` instead of `[0,1,2,3]`

Is there a nice way to do this in python/numpy using list comprehension or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You just need go clip the lower index at zero:

```
>>> print(a[max(i-2,0):i+2+1])
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Without this, it can got into negative numbers. This has special meaning in slicing: negative indices count from the *end* of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You've tripped across the right-end numbering of Python.  You gave it the limits [-1:3], but `-1` denotes the right-hand element.  Since the "first" element is past the "last" element, the resulting slice is 0.  You won't have this problem on the high indices, because there's no "wrap-around" on that end.

Simply drive the lower index to a rail of 0, using `max`.

```
print(a[max(i-2, 0)]:i+2+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you exit the bounds of the list, it returns an empty list. Try:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
i = 1
interval=2
print( a[ max(i-2, 0) : min(i+2+1, len(a)) ] )
```

I just put max/min bounds on it so it doesn't escape it. Not very pythonic, but it's a quick fix.